# Uploading files to Synology NAS with frpascal code using FileStation API

Tags: file-upload, freepascal, lazarus, synology

I'm playing with a Synology NAS and trying to use its SYNO.FileStation API with freepascal code. All its functions work correctly when I use TFPHTTPClient component GET functions, however when I try to upload a file with POST, I always got an error code:105 which means the logged in session does not have permission.

Beside the `syno_token`, I also tried to include `did` and `sid` values from the the `ResponseContent` given back by the NAS at the first part of the code, but the result was always the same. My code so far is this:

```pascal
function TSynologyNAS.UploadFile(const SourceFilePath, DestinationFolder: string): Boolean;
var
  S, synotoken, did, sid: string;
  FormData: TStrings;
  ResponseContent: TStringList;
  Url: string;
  HTTPClient: TFPHTTPClient;
begin
  Result := False;
  


  // Initialize FormData to include the file in the request
  FormData := TStringList.Create;
  try
    FormData.Add('file=' + sourceFilePath); // Assuming simple form data
    // Create an instance of TFPHTTPClient
    HTTPClient := TFPHTTPClient.Create(nil);
    ResponseContent := TStringList.Create;
    HTTPClient.Get(FBaseURL + 'entry.cgi?api=SYNO.API.Auth&version=6&method=login&account=' + FUserName + '&passwd=' + FPassword + '&enable_syno_token=yes', ResponseContent);
    S:= ResponseContent.Text;
    synotoken := Trim(ParseJSONValue(S, 'data.synotoken').AsString);
    did:=  Trim(ParseJSONValue(S, 'data.did').AsString);
    sid:= Trim(ParseJSONValue(S, 'data.sid').AsString);
    // Construct the URL for uploading the file
    Url := FBaseURL + 'entry.cgi?api=SYNO.FileStation.Upload&version=3&method=upload&path=' + HTTPencode(DestinationFolder) +
    '&overwrite=true&filename=' + HTTPEncode(Trim(ExtractFileName(SourceFilePath))) + '&SynoToken=' + synotoken;
    try
      // Perform the file upload using the POST method
      HTTPClient.AddHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + synotoken);
      HTTPClient.FormPost(Url, FormData, ResponseContent);
      Result := True;
    except
      // Handle exceptions if any
      on E: Exception do
      begin
        Result := False;
        ShowMessage('Error: ' + E.Message);
      end;
    end;
  finally
    ResponseContent.Free;
    FormData.Free;
    HTTPClient.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Is there anyone who has experience with Synology NAS and can give me some advice about this?